# How to solve for matrix inside equation?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following equation from the Dicom standard to calculate the voxel position in space from a point in an image plane where

> Pxyz The coordinates of the voxel (i,j) in the frame's image plane in
>   units of mm.
>
> Sxyz The three values of Image Position (Patient) (0020,0032). It is
>   the location in mm from the origin of the RCS.
>
> Xxyz The values from the row (X) direction cosine of Image Orientation
>   (Patient) (0020,0037).
>
> Yxyz The values from the column (Y) direction cosine of Image
>   Orientation (Patient) (0020,0037).
>
> i Column index to the image plane. The first column is index zero.
>
> Δi Column pixel resolution of Pixel Spacing (0028,0030) in units of
>   mm.
>
> j Row index to the image plane. The first row index is zero.
>
> Δj Row pixel resolution of Pixel Spacing (0028,0030) in units of mm.

[image: Image Position and Image Orientation Matrix]

What I want to do is solve the whole thing for the image plane coordinate (i,j) parts.  I *think* what I need to do is multiply by the inverse of the  XxΔiYxΔj0Sx (etc) part.

1) Is that correct?
Answer from comment:

> matrix is not invertible because its third column is a zero column

1.A) Maybe this is stupid, but it looks to me like that third column is unnecessary.  Isn't this 3x3 equivalent?

[image: 3x3 matrix]

2) How do I get the inverse of that <del>4x4</del>  3x3 matrix?

Comment: Yes, computing the inverse matrix should have been the solution, but this matrix is not invertible because its third column is a zero column....

Comment: Thanks!  Please see my followup (possibly stupid) question. And if I'm wrong, what is another way to solve for i and j?  The only other thing I can think of is turn it into algebraic equations and do substitution (pretty ugly though)

Comment: Yes you can leave out the last row since it doesn't involve any variables. The way to go now is to solve the Linear system. But for the love of all that is holy do not invert the matrix. This is the most inefficient way to go about things. Use a numerical solver or compute an LU decomposition instead.

Comment: @Hyperplane No,  the last row has to be considered because the OP deals in fact with homogeneous coordinates (see my answer). Concerning a small size matrix (here  $3 \times 3$), it is not a sin to consider direct inversion by using the explicit formulas with a warning if the determinant is close to zero,

Comment: Would be super awesome if downvoters explained the downvote :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, the $3 \times 3$ system is equivalent to the previous one (I should have noted it...)

2) Let $M$ denote this $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Inverting the equation means that

$U:=\begin{pmatrix}i\\j\\1\end{pmatrix}$ should be equal to $V:=M^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}P_x\\P_y\\P_z\end{pmatrix}.$

The apparently big problem is that the third coordinate of $V$ has no reason to be equal to $1$.

But in fact, as this $1$ coordinate has to be considered in the context of  homogeneous coordinates (have you been introduced to them ?), the real relationship betwen $U$ and $V$ is that their coordinates are not **equal** but are **proportional**.

Therefore, take

$$i=V(1)/V(3), \ \ j=V(2)/V(3).$$

---

**Remark:** I advise you to do the computation of $M^{-1}$ with the usual formulas:

if $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&d&g\\b&e&h\\c&f&i\end{pmatrix}$ (I take the simplest notations ; beware that the $i$ here is not the coordinate $i$ seen before), then:

$$M^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det(M)}\begin{pmatrix} ei - fh& fg - di& dh - eg\\
ch - bi& ai - cg& bg - ah\\
bf - ce& cd - af& ae - bd \end{pmatrix},$$

where $\det(M)=aei + bfg + cdh - afh - bdi  -ceg.$

with a warning if this determinant is too close from zero.